# Regexp for validation in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am trying to write a RegEx for password validaion to be used but I can not figure out how to do it correctly.
My RegEx so far looks like:

```
regexp = "^(?=.*[0-9]){1,3}(?=.*[a-zA-Z]){1,3}(?=\\s+$)$"
```

Regarding to the password rules:

A) It must include numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters.

B) The number of letters or numbers in a row must be smaller than 4.(e.g. both 1234 and dcba are not allowed)

C) The number of same characters is no more than 3. (e.g. both aaaa and 0000 are not allowed)
Thanks.

Comment: what is the question? if the question is how is the regex: i don't think that is possible to check it with a single regex

Comment: I thought it is possible to do it with a single regexp. But what is the way out?

Comment: A) no because the order is not fixed (is it?) and for B): you would have to write every possibility down

Comment: you should check everything extra (in methods for example) if it is correct and if you combine all you got your validity | even if it would be possible the regex would be very long and unreadable

Comment: because you asked on the answer beyond: C): it is easier to split it to characters and count them | a regex cannot count (except you have a fixed order of the letters - see comment above)

Comment: You were write with that. I just did one regexp to check if are there digits, upper and lower letters, without spaces and than wrought two methods via I cought find out how many digits and letters are in line at all and how many characters are repeatable (if (count>3) false). Thanks.

Comment: may I wrote a answer so you can check it?

Comment: Yes, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible to check it with a single regex.
Even if it would be possible the regex would be very long and unreadable.

Here some reasons:

- A) no because the order is not fixed (is it?)
- B) you would have to write every possibility down *(see A)*
- C) a regex cannot count *(see A)*

You should check everything extra (in methods for example) if it is correct and if you combine all you got your validity.

For C for example: split to characters and count them.
A hint for performance improvements: if you check one and it is false - don't check the others (also in the methods itself).

**In general**: *a regex is a expression which checks if the string has the correct characters in the correct order*.

So you can check if it is a valid http(s) request because the order is fixed and only the domain changes. But the (simple) basic is: `http` + optional `s` + `//` +  minimum 3 characters (specific one) + `.` + minimum 3 characters (specific one).
[Here are some other good examples.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done with just a single regex. Instead come up with an algorithm that scans the string (password) and validates your requirements for said password.

Comment: Technically speaking it can but it would be a huge and very inefficient algorythm especially when it comes to max number values... Botom line is that it would be really impractical :) 

P.S. cool name!

Comment: Ok, I agree with you. But what is the regex to check how many same characters I have in the string (I mean part "C" from my question). I want to write three separate regex for every point ("A", "B", "C"). Is this a good idea?Thanks.